# Pointer difference when creating an object inside or outside a class

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

I'm in the process of wrapping my head around how polymorphism works in C++.

I wrote a small program, and noticed something that seems odd to me; a pointer to the first item of a list inside a (derived) class is different when I create the item of that list inside the class, while it does match up when I create the item outside of the class.

I've had trouble searching for this problem, because many keywords I use will lead me to general tutorials/questions on polymorphism, but none from which I could find an answer to what's happening.

Let's say I have some abstract class `Shape`:

```cpp
// Shape.h

class Item;

class Shape {
public:
    virtual void PrintClassName() = 0;
    virtual bool AddItem(Item* item) {
        ItemCollection.push_back(item);
        item->Location = this;
        return true;
    }
    virtual Item* GetItem() {
        return *ItemCollection.begin();
    }
    virtual int GetNumItems() {
        return ItemCollection.size();
    }
private:
    std::list<Item*> ItemCollection;
};
```

The purpose of this class to hold some items:

```
// Item.h
class Shape;

class Item {
public:
    Shape* Location;
};
```

And because `Shape` is an abstract class, I need a concrete derived class, `Square`. Now, something I want `Square` to do (but not other shapes!) is to be able to create `Item`s itself (via the `CreateNewItem()` function).

```cpp
// Square.h
class Square : public Shape {
public:
    virtual void PrintClassName() {
        std::cout << "Square" << std::endl;
    }

    virtual bool CreateNewItem() {
        Item newItem;
        Item* newItem_ptr = &newItem;
        this->AddItem(newItem_ptr);
        return true;
    }
};
```

I wrote some tests to see if everything was working as intended. The results surprised me, as I expected the top and bottom test to behave the same, but they give different results on the final test (see code below). The only difference between the two tests is whether or not I'm creating an item from inside the `Square` class. I can't understand why, in the second test, I'm not getting the pointer that I'm expecting.

```cpp
// Main.cpp

// helper function for tests
void Assert(std::string description, bool a) {
    if (a) {
        std::cout << "  Success: [" << description << "]" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    std::cout << "  FAIL: [" << description << "]" << std::endl;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    {
        Square square;
        Square* square_ptr = &square;

        // Initial state
        Assert("Initial empty Square", square_ptr->GetNumItems() == 0);

        // Create Item
        Item item;
        Item* item_ptr = &item;
        Assert("Add item to Square", square_ptr->AddItem(item_ptr));
        Assert("Square contains 1 item", square_ptr->GetNumItems() == 1);
        Assert("Item in Square is the above created item", square_ptr->GetItem() == item_ptr);
        Assert("Location of the item is the Square", item_ptr->Location == square_ptr);
    }
    std::cout << "- - - - - -" << std::endl;
    {
        Square square;
        Square* square_ptr = &square;

        // Initial state
        Assert("Initial empty Square", square_ptr->GetNumItems() == 0);

        // Create Item using Square's fuction
        Assert("Add item to Square", square_ptr->CreateNewItem());
        Assert("Square contains 1 item", square_ptr->GetNumItems() == 1);
        Item* item_ptr = square_ptr->GetItem();
        Assert("Location of the item is the Square", item_ptr->Location == square_ptr);
    }
}
```

```
// Results from the console:

  Success: [Initial empty Square]
  Success: [Add item to Square]
  Success: [Square contains 1 item]
  Success: [Item in Square is the above created item]
  Success: [Location of the item is the Square]
- - - - - -
  Success: [Initial empty Square]
  Success: [Add item to Square]
  Success: [Square contains 1 item]
  FAIL: [Location of the item is the Square]
```

Can anybody explain to me what the difference is between the two approaches? Why is the last test failing? What do I need to do to make it work? If possible, in C++03, as I'm trying to see from where the language has grown before introducing too many modern features.

[Code on Godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/8KGejnKfz)

Comment: `CreateNewItem` takes address of a local and passes it to `AddItem` which on exit of  `CreateNewItem` the local `Item newItem;` is destroyed thus the pointer is no-longer valid.

Comment: `Item newItem; Item* newItem_ptr = &newItem; this->AddItem(newItem_ptr);` And poof, that local variable goes up into a puff of smoke when the function returns.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with polymorphism, and everything to do with object/variable scope and lifetimes.

Comment: Rule-of-thumb: if you see a pointer being assigned the address of a local; you need to make sure that the address is not used for longer than the life-time of the local.  Pointers to locals are _"code-smell"_.

Comment: Thanks for your reactions. I feel dumb for not noticing. I was thinking that pointer would remain valid once it was stored in the list, but I have only stored the pointer, not the object itself, so it would disappear. Thanks everyone, I have been tearing my hair out for hours.

Comment: ot: `Item` is fine with an incomplete / forward declared `Shape`, but not the other way around.